# How does the 'Change Explorer' view work in RTC source control

Tags: clearcase, rtc

I have a component which contains outgoing changes :

[image]

When I right click this component and compare against the 'initial baseline' I get a list of change sets which comprise this component. This is displayed in the 'Change Explorer' view :

[image]

Is this the list of change sets over time that have been delivered to this component or change sets that have been delivered to a baseline, or is it both ?

By right clicking on each change set I see the option to 'accept' the change set. Should this copy the selected changeset into my workspace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see accept on a changeset, that means it is part of the incoming changes, done and delivered over time on the stream.
If you accept those, and if your component is loaded in your sandbox, then yes, those files will be copied over on your hard drive.

---

To be clearer, the "Change Explorer" (compared to your classic "Pending Changes" view) is about source control *exploration* (ie finding, *and if needed, accepting* old changeset that you need to see back in your repo workspace, and, if the corresponding component is loaded, in your sandbox or hard-drive)

See "[Practicing source control archaeology with Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/library/article/447/)"

> Choosing `Open in Change Explorer` on a change set will show you the all the file versions and directories involved in that change set.
>   Decorators and clarifying comments are displayed to help your understanding of what had occurred:
>
> - File or directory changed: [image: file changed] [image: directory changed]
> - File or directory added: [image: file added] [image: directory added]
> - File or directory deleted: [image: file deleted] [image: directory deleted]

[image: change explorer]

Comment: When I accept a change set from the 'Change Explorer' view the files are not being updated on my hard-drive. The component is loaded onto my hard drive. No errors are being thrown when I accept the change set. Is there a log file or some other method of checking whats happening when I accept the change set ?

Comment: @user470184 you can check out the "Errors view", it contains any exception that might have occurred during the RTC operations.

Comment: @user470184 Just to be sure, why your first picture is about a component with an arrow pointing to the *right*? Any right-oriented arrow is about changes you need to deliver, not changes you could accept.

Comment: @user470184 see the first picture of https://jazz.net/library/article/125/#id7 for instance, it states: " Figure 7.1 shows what his workspace typically looks like. His workspace named 'Source Control Workspace' is caught up with the latest from his team's stream 'Source Control'. I.e. there are no incoming change sets to accept."

Comment: Yes I am delivering changes, but before I deliver them it seems I have the option to accept a previous change set by :1. right click on the component within 'Pending Changes' 2. Click 'Compare With' 3. Select a baseline . This displays the 'Change Explorer' view, the picture at jazz.net/library/article/125/#id7 is within 'Pending Changes' view, whereas I'm referring to 'Change Explorer' to accept changes.

Comment: By "Errors View" you mean "Error Log" ? No errors are being reported

Comment: @user470184 You should only accept changes that are displayed in the "Incoming" section of your "Pending changes" view. You don't have to go all the way in the "Change Explorer" view to accept changes from an arbitrary flow target that you selected. The primary flow target of your repository workspace is your Stream, and the "Pending Changes" view is there to notify you of any changes present in the Stream and not yet in your repository workspace (hence "Incoming").

Comment: What if I wanted to accept changes from a previous change set that flows to this stream ? Maybe there is a better way to accomplish this. It is misleading although to apparently give the option of accepting previous change sets using the 'Change Explorer' view and not report any error if the change set has not been locally applied.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, I think this is becoming a separate question.

Comment: @user470184 Ok. In your next question, try to detail a bit more the exact step you follow to accept those changes, and also what you want to achieve.

Comment: @user470184 I realized my answer wasn't enough about the "Change Explorer", so I added a section to my answer.